# Role-based authentication with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to Firebase, I am trying to create user authentication.  A user object has: username, email, fullname, role, password.

Now I want to be able to create a user with those properties and authenticate using either username/email and password.

After authentication I would like to check the role of the user to determine which part of my app they are allowed to access.

I have no idea how to go about it and the docs mostly deal with only email and password.

Comment: Firebase just launched support for role based access via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 1):

Firebase only supports email + password authentication at the moment, and not username + password.  (And, of course, Facebook, Twitter, anonymous, etc.)  You can still do you own custom authentication, though.

You can still create your own user objects in the database with those fields that you mentioned: (username, email, fullname, role, password), but those are separate from the authentication part of firebase.  This process, I would call "registration," and that's up to you to implement.

If you're wanting to control what parts of the database different users can access then you're talking about [database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

If you want to control access to different parts of your app itself, then you would just code it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your database like this to store each user's information using their `$uid` and keep a list of the usernames claimed by each user so you can have a write rule that prevents overwriting an already existing username in `usernames`.

So upon registration, you need to sign up with an email and password using `FIRAuth` then on completion, you will be given a `FIRUser`. You can then use the `uid` to write the username, role etc. to the user's location in the database  `"users/$uid": {"username": "callam", ...}` as well as the username individually at the usernames location `"usernames/$username": "$uid"`.

You will need to implement write/validate rules for `"users/$uid"` and `"usernames/$username"` to make sure the username hasn't already been taken.

```
{
    "users": {
        $uid: {
            "username": "callam",
            ...
            "role": "member"
        }
    },
    "usernames": {
        "callam": $uid
    }
}
```